# How to construct regex for this text

Tags: python, regex

Here's the input:

```
7. Data 1 1. STR1 STR2 3. 12345 4. 0876 9. NO 2 1. STR 2. STRT STR 3. 9909090 5. YES 6. NO 7. YES 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 ZŁ 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO 3 1. STRT 2. STRT 3. 63110300291 5. YES 6. NO 7. NO 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 ZŁ 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO 4 1. QWERET 2. IOSTR9 3. 76012509879 5. YES 6. NO 7. NO 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 XX 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO 0 1.
```

And here's expected output:

```
[('1', '1. STR1 STR2 3. 12345 4. 0876 9. NO'),
('2', '1. STR 2. STRT STR 3. 9909090 5. YES 6. NO 7. YES 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 ZŁ 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO'),
('3', '1. STRT 2. STRT 3. 63110300291 5. YES 6. NO 7. NO 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 ZŁ 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO'),
('4', '1. QWERET 2. IOSTR9 3. 76012509879 5. YES 6. NO 7. NO 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 XX 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO')]
```

I've tried this:

```
re.findall(r'(?=\s(\d+)\s(1\..*?)\s\d+\s1\.)', txt, re.DOTALL)
```

But of course it's not right solution - regex have to match `(\d+) 1.` but not `PRub. 1 1.`.
What should I do to make it work?

Comment: @sudo_O I can't read input string, it is too long! Get it back!

Comment: @loldop formatting is important, questions should be formatted to make clear if the input is a single line or multi-line. Use the vertical scroll bar to read the string.

Comment: @sudo_O I know, but you can imagine, that it is one line with `\n`. I prefer to use imagination, not scrolling in big string situation

Comment: @Kiro, is this text belong to "social tests" or something?

Comment: I can't see using imagination leading to correct answers. Question should be explicit!

Comment: @loldop No, I have to parse some information about companies, from plain text (I've replaced real data with random STRS).

Comment: @sudo_O okay, let's think about answer :) I think, that OP can split it by first data `\d\.\s\w+\s*\w*`

Comment: from the input example it is not clear how to find the start of the next "record". could you describe how to identify the start of a new record?

Comment: Is this some kind of standard data? if so what standard?

Comment: @CaptSolo Every record starts with "\d+ 1\.", e.g. "1 1.", "2 1.", but sometimes record has "PRub \d \1." inside. So: "1 1. ABC PRub 1 1. EFG 2 1. HIJ" -> [('1', '1. ABC PRub 1 1. EFG"), ('2', '1. HIJ')]

Comment: Is it all in one continuous line with no line breaks?

Comment: Don't obsess over creating a one line RegEx to solve this for you, breaking it into stages will be more maintainable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is this:

```
In [1]: s='7. Data 1 1. STR1 STR2 3. 12345 4. 0876 9. NO 2 1. STR 2. STRT STR 3. 9909090 5. YES 6. NO 7. YES 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 ZŁ 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO 3 1. STRT 2. STRT 3. 63110300291 5. YES 6. NO 7. NO 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 ZŁ 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO 4 1. QWERET 2. IOSTR9 3. 76012509879 5. YES 6. NO 7. NO 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 XX 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO 0 1.'

In [2]: import re

In [3]: re.findall('(?<=\s)\d.*?(?=\s\d\s\d[.](?=$|\s[A-Z]))',s)
Out[3]: 
['1 1. STR1 STR2 3. 12345 4. 0876 9. NO',
 '2 1. STR 2. STRT STR 3. 9909090 5. YES 6. NO 7. YES 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 Z\xc5\x81 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO',
 '3 1. STRT 2. STRT 3. 63110300291 5. YES 6. NO 7. NO 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 Z\xc5\x81 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO',
 '4 1. QWERET 2. IOSTR9 3. 76012509879 5. YES 6. NO 7. NO 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 XX 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO']
```

For you exact output I'd do something like:

```
In [4]: ns = re.findall('(?<=\s)\d.*?(?=\s\d\s\d[.](?=$|\s[A-Z]))',s)

In [5]: [tuple(f.split(' ',1)) for f in ns]
Out[5]: 
[('1', '1. STR1 STR2 3. 12345 4. 0876 9. NO'),
 ('2', '1. STR 2. STRT STR 3. 9909090 5. YES 6. NO 7. YES 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 Z\xc5\x81 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO'),
 ('3', '1. STRT 2. STRT 3. 63110300291 5. YES 6. NO 7. NO 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 Z\xc5\x81 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO'),
 ('4', '1. QWERET 2. IOSTR9 3. 76012509879 5. YES 6. NO 7. NO 8. NO 9. YES 10. 5000 XX 11. 1000 XX 12. NO PRub. 1 1. 1000 XX 2. NO')]
```

Might be a better way to do this but my python foo isn't as good as my regexp foo.

**Regexplanation:**

```
(?<=\s) # Use positive look-behind to match a leading space but don't include it
\d      # match digit    
.*?     # Match everything up till the next record (lazy)
        # The following positive look-behinds is the key. It matches the start of
        # each new record i.e
        # 2 1. S
        # 3 1. S
        # 4 1. Q
        # 0 1.$ 
        # look-arounds match but don't seek past.  
(?=\s\d\s\d[.](?=$|\s[A-Z]))
(?=     # positive look-ahead 1
\s      # space
\d      # digit
\s      # space
\d      # digit
[.]     # period
(?=     # postive look-ahead 2 
$       # end of string
|       # OR
\s[A-Z] # space followed by uppercase letter
)       # close look-ahead 1
)       # close look-ahead 2
```

Comment: "NO" can be anything else in some other case. We should only look at "PRub" word

Comment: @Kiro think I cracked it, test new regexp.

Comment: Thanks! Works great for all my cases!

Comment: Added an explanation, the key is look-arounds check here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for more info.

Comment: +1 for "regexplanation" :)